# Split Purchase Order according to Product Category

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I wanna split the Purchase Order according to Product Category.

**My Code so far:**

```
_inherit ='purchase.order.line'  
split = fields.Boolean(string='Split')


_inherit ='purchase.order'
def btn_split_rfq(self):
            flag = []
            for record in self: 
                if record.order_line:
                    for rec in record.order_line:
                        rec.split = True # oles tis eggrafes true
                        flag.append(rec.product_id.categ_id.id) # lista me ta categ ids
                        newlist=[ii for n,ii in enumerate(flag) if ii not in flag[:n]] # ta krata mono mia fora an uparxoun polles
                    for index in newlist: # gia 2 katigories 8a treksi 2 fores
                        quotation_id = self.copy()
                        for index in record.order_line:
                            if index.split:
                                self.env['purchase.order.line'].browse(index.id).unlink() 
                else:
                    raise ValidationError(_('Please Select Order Line To Split'))
```

The code so far, is split to multiple POs e.g. if i have 2 type of categories is making 2 POs but and the two POs is taking and the 4 products not only of product category(see image below).

**Output**:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**But i want this kind of Output:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my problem, i dont think is pretty but it does the job. Thanks @ CZoellner and @Charif DZ for the effort!!!

```
   def btn_split_rfq(self):
            flag =[]
            for record in self: 
                if record.order_line:
                   for rec in record.order_line: #run for all products on purchase order
                        flag.append(rec.product_id.categ_id.id) # append product  category ids
                        categ_ids=[ii for n,ii in enumerate(flag) if ii not in flag[:n]] # filter list,keep only one time every product category id
                        categ_ids.sort() # sorting list
                   for index in categ_ids: # will run 2 times if there is 2 product categories
                           quotations_ids = [self.copy()]
                           for order_line in quotations_ids:
                               prods = self.env['purchase.order.line'].search([('product_categ_id' ,'!=',index),('order_id','=',int(order_line))])
                               for ids in prods:
                                   self.env['purchase.order.line'].browse(ids.id).unlink() 
                else:
                     raise ValidationError(_('Not Available Purchase Order Lines'))
```

Comment: I think you should use CZollner's code is less complicated than your logic if you are working in a team.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to just ignore your code example, because it is difficult to understand for me. If you want try out my attempt:

```py
def button_split_by_prod_categ(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    groups = {}
    # group lines by product category
    for line in self.order_line:
        if line.product_id.categ_id not in groups:
            groups[line.product_id.categ_id] = line
        else:
            groups[line.product_id.categ_id] =| line
    skip = True
    orders = self
    for lines in groups.values():
        # skip first group
        if skip:
            skip = False
            continue
        # or create a new order without lines and connect
        # the group's lines with it
        else:
            default_values = {'order_line': []}
            new_order = self.copy(default=default_values)
            lines.write({'order_id': new_order.id})
            orders |= new_order
    # now you could return a list view with all orders
    # or just do 'nothing'
    return
```

Comment: @OmaL for what this edit? `categ` is not needed in the  for each loop.

Comment: `orders |= self.copy({'order_line':[(6,0,lines.ids)]})` I think this will automatically add lines in the copy process and add the new order to orders set in the same time.

Comment: you can always use `4` instead,  `[(4, line.id) for line in lines]`

Comment: Yes that would be possible, but i like my solution :-P

Comment: up vote then :p, But I think you should pass the empty list in `copy`, not with `with_context` did you try your code I think default will work only if there is no value for `order_line` but copy will pass the lines of origin record?

Comment: That's a good point, i think both ways are possible in this case, but your way is the better one.